# How to render the_field(); string with a <iframe> tag' as HTML?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im printing out a text string which have an `<iframe>` html tag - however the iframe tag is not rendered as HTML but just text. **How do I make the string render as HTML?**

I've not had any luck with `strip_tags();` nor `htmlentities();`

```
<?php echo the_field('video_content'); ?>
```

On the page (frontend'wise) this renders as text:

```
<iframe width=”760″ height=”428″ src=”https://www.youtube.com/embed/qQIsdod0LWo” frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In the HTML it renders as:

```
<p>&lt;iframe width=”760″ height=”428″ src=”https://www.youtube.com/embed/qQIsdod0LWo” frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</p>
```

Comment: The content of the string you're outputting is the whole `<iframe..../>` code?

Comment: Yup, you can see the whole iframe string in the second code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `html_entity_decode()` instead of `htmlentitie()`.

*For Example:*

```
<?php

    $orig = '<p>&lt;iframe width=”760″ height=”428″ src=”https://www.youtube.com/embed/qQIsdod0LWo” frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</p>';

    $b = html_entity_decode($orig);

    echo $b;

?>
```

*Output:*

```
<p><iframe width=”760″ height=”428″ src=”https://www.youtube.com/embed/qQIsdod0LWo” frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```